# PhpStorm How to Automatically Determine Dimensions of Image

Tags: html, image, dimensions, phpstorm

I moved from Dreamweaver to PhpStorm for my PHP/HTML/CSS development. There is a cool feature in Dreamweaver where you can drag an image from the file explorer into the code and it would generate the `<img>` tag with the appropriate width and height dimensions. Is there a way to do something similar in the PhpStorm IDE?

I've also asked this question on [their forum](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/thread/312089).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> code completion for attributes or Zen Templates and <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to expand values automatically. More details available in the forum reply.

Comment: Why not post the complete answer from the forum post? You got the jist, but the complete answer is even more helpful.